# Помогите понять логику цикла

Tags: java

Наткнулся на метод вычиления простых чисел, писал не я, нашел на форуме
http://www.cyberforum.ru/post9525900.html

```
public class Ex4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, arg;
    for (num = 2; num <= 100; num++) {
        for (arg = 2; (num % arg) > 0; arg++) {
        }
        if (arg == num)
            System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
}
```

Помогите понять логику второго цикла for, почему при каждом простом числе num, arg = 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (arg = 2; (num % arg) > 0; arg++)
```

тут

```
(num % arg) > 0
```

это проверка на деление целых чисел без остатка. Т.е., если мы делим два числа и получаем целое число, то (num % arg) = 0.
Пример: num=4,arg=2. Их частное будет равно 2.
num=9,arg=3. Частное равно 3.

Если, в результате деления получается дробное число, то условие не цикл будет идти до тех пор, пока не получит целое число при деление.
Пример: num=9,arg=2. (num % arg) = 1. Проходим цикл и делаем arg++. arg ,будет равно 3. Следовательно (num % arg) = 0. Выходим из цикла.

Если бы arg=1, то цикл сразу прекращал бы свою работу, так как деление чисел на 1, всегда будет равно числу. Ну а с 0 нельзя начать, так как на него нельзя делить. Получается самое маленькое число - это 2!

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. Я никак не мог понять логику условия второго цикла. Теперь понял, что он будет выполнятся, инкрементируя аргумент, пока результат деления по модулю не будет больше 0.

Answer (score 0):

[Последовательность простых чисел начинается так:2, 3, 5, 7...](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)
По этому цикл начинается с 2х